# App deployment issue to Bluemix from Eclipse using sample JavaCloudandApp

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-cloud

I downloaded the Bluemix demo JavaCloudantAPP war file.  I have been trying to get sample app loaded from Eclipse, but constantly get the error 'Error preforming operation: Service label must not be null.'

I've looked everywhere for that silly variable/label, but cannot find it anywhere.  Can anyone help?

Thx

Comment: are you getting the error when you try to import the war file? or when you to deploy to Bluemix?

Comment: When I try to deploy to Bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

Check your VCAP_Services variable.  There should be a label for the Cloudant service such as this:

```
  "cloudantNoSQLDB": {
    "name": "Cloudant-3s",
    "label": "cloudantNoSQLDB",
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was that I first created the cloudant no sql service on the bluemix - either thru the bluemix webui, or via cf create-service , then updated the name in the manifest.yml , such that
services:
  -

The difference here is that when I attempt to deploy to the server, the service list shows the name and the actual service instance it will get bounded to.